# ngSelect in Angular showing weird behavior

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular, I have the following code:

```
<select id="selectUser" class="form-control" ng-change="selectAction()" ng-model="users"
        ng-options="value.SignOnId as value.UserName for value in users">
            <option value="">Select a User</option>
</select>
```

As soon as I select a value from the drop down, it executes the **selectAction()** method and then all values from the drop down disappear, can anybody tell me what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

change this: ng-model="users" to ng-model="user"

When you select the user, you are setting the users variable to be the selected user, which means your ng-options no-longer has options in it.